# Code for Alpha Numeric used in Regular Expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need code for alpha numeric ,which is used in regular expression in asp.net to enter the data inside the textbox .

Answer (score 3):

Regex for alpha numeric:
`"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"`
If you don't want  empty strings, use + instead of *.

Answer (score 1):

I guess below should be enough.

```
^[0-9A-Za-z]*$
```

Here is the break down

```
^ indicates start of the string
0-9 all number from 0 to 9
A-Z all Upper case character
a-z all small case character
* indicates 0 or more character
$ end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.@]{0,25}$"`. It accepts `.` and `@` symbol also. If not remove them

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.@]{0,25}$" ErrorMessage="Only Alphanumeric"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```